# Coins out of different boxes

Tags: probability

I have 3 boxes with a total of 9 coins in them.
First box contains 3 gold coins,

second box 2 gold coins and one silver coin and

the last box  one gold and two silver coins.

A box is chosen at random. A gold coin is found inside it. 
What is the chance that the same box contains at least another gold coin.

For my solution I consider the following sets:

F: the first coin is gold

G: at least another coin is golden

$B_i, i=1,2,3: $ choose box i:

Now I have to calculate the following:

$$P(G|F)=  \frac{P(G\cap F)}{P(F)} $$

For $P(F) $ I can use the law of total probability:

$P(F)=\sum_{i=1}^3 P(B_i) \cdot P(F|B_i)= \frac{2}{3} $

How can I get $P(G\cap F) $
Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event G can be reinterpreted as **Box 3 not chosen**
Therefore, $P(GF) =P(G) P(F|G)$. 
Here, $P(G) = 2/3$ and $P(F|G) =5/6$.
As you have already calculated the denominator to be $2/3$, therefore final answer is $5/6$

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to compute $F \cap G$ directly?

Comment: It has to be 5/9

Comment: Direct computation of intersection is only possible when all sample points of considered sample space have equal probability of occurrence.In this case ,it isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: By the way, How did you arrive at 5/9?  It should be 5/6.

Comment: $\frac{5/9}{2/3}$

Comment: I wanted to get  $P( F\cap G) = \frac{5}{9}$